# Define $f$ and $g$ on $ℤ_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ by $f(x) = (x + 4)^2$ mod $5$ and $g(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$ mod $5$, then $f = g?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

May I know what step do I need to do for this question to check if $f=g?$

Let $ℤ_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and define functions $f, g :ℤ_5 → ℤ_5$ as follows: 
$f(x) = (x + 4)^2 \mod 5,$ and $g(x) = (x^2 + 3x + 1) \mod 5$. Is $f = g ?$

I expanded out $f(x)=
(x + 4)^2 = x^2 + 8x + 16$
and I am stuck on how to continue.

Comment: Hints: 4 and -1 are congruent mod 5, as are 3 and -2.

Comment: According to definition, two functions $f, g$ are equal if $ f(x)=g(x) $ for every $ x$ in their common domain. So, check the values $ 0, 1, ...,4$ one by one!

Comment: The notation $\mathbb Z_1$ for $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is most snobbish.

Comment: Hint (if one wishes to avoid to check the $5$ values): For every $x$, $f(x)-g(x)=5(x+3)$.

Comment: Since you've already gotten other answers: $x+4 \equiv x-1$, so $f(x)$ is really $(x-1)^2$.  And $x^2+3x+1 \equiv x^2-2x+1$, so $g(x)$ is really $x^2-2x+1$.  Now you can do the squaring and see they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal to each other, we must have 3 conditions:

- same domain
- same codomain
- same laws

By hypothesis, you have the first two conditions already checked. So all you need to prove is the equality of formation laws:

note that:

$$f(0) = 1,f(1) = 0,f(2) = 1,f(3) = 4,f(4) = 4$$

$$g(0) = 1, g(1) = 0,g(2) = 1,g(3) = 4,g(4) = 4$$

therefore $f=g$

**edit:**

if you want use $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_5$, you can use module algebra:

\begin{align*}
a & \equiv b \pmod{c} \implies \alpha \equiv \alpha b \pmod{c}\\
a & \equiv b \pmod{c} \implies a+x \equiv b+x \pmod{c}\\
a & \equiv b \pmod{c} \implies a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod{c}
\end{align*}

so:
\begin{align*}
f(x) & \equiv (x+4)^2 \pmod{5}\\ 
     & \equiv x^2+8x+16 \pmod{5}\\ 
     & \equiv x^2+8x+1 \pmod{5}\\ 
     & \equiv x^2+3x+1\pmod{5}
\end{align*} 
since 
$$16 = 15+1 \implies 16 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$$
and 
$$8 = 5+3 \implies 8 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$$

$$g(x) \equiv x^2+3x+1 \pmod{5}$$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $f$ and $g$ is 
$$\begin{align} f(x)-g(x)= & (x+4)^2-(x^2+3x+1) \\ & =5x+15 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \end {align}$$
for every integer $x$. Hence $f$ and $g$ coincide, as they both are defined on $\mathbb{Z}/ 5\mathbb{Z}$.